# Jquery error appears at the bottom of the browser when on my Wordpress homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a theme to build a website and at the bottom of the browser window (not the site) there is the following message:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({ items:1, itemsDesktop:[1000,1], itemsDesktopSmall:[979,1], itemsTablet:[768,1], pagination: true, autoPlay:true }); });
```

[image]

I am not a programmer so don't understand Javascript, I am not using Owl Carousel and the home page seems to be the only page this message is on.

Just wondering how I rectify this, or just remove it if it is some sort of stray piece of code.

Any help would be really appreciated,

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "bottom of the browser window"? The status bar? The console?

Comment: Think it is the status bar, ive added an image of it

Comment: If you aren't using owlCarousel, I would search through the files and see where this is being included and simply get rid of it.

Comment: This looks like it *is* part of the page; there's probably a small syntax error in one of the template files which causes JS source to display as regular HTML text. Look at the theme's footer.php (or post it here, or better, tell us the URL of your website)

Comment: thanks, have solved the problem, was some stray code from when the site was updated a year ago in an old theme